# Count specific value from list object using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Get count of same value in list object using jquery. using Ajax call method i get list object on client side but i don't know how to get count of same value in each row object.

In that PO_NM is same in other object i want that count like

Chemical- 2
    Electrical- 2
    Water -1

[{"ID":13,"PO_ID":1,"PO_NM":"Chemical","POINT_NAME":"TES HFJGH  KH"},{"ID":13,"PO_ID":1,"PO_NM":"Chemical","POINT_NAME":"KRUTIKA PATEL"},{"ID":14,"PO_ID":2,"PO_NM":"Electrical","POINT_NAME":"SDA SHFKJ KJSJDHF KJSHDKJ JK"},{"ID":14,"PO_ID":2,"PO_NM":"Electrical","POINT_NAME":"KJHG S DJKFH JSKJSDKJFH KJ"},{"ID":15,"PO_ID":3,"PO_NM":"Water","POINT_NAME":"ERTERSHFKJ HNSJFH KJS"}]"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akWDn.jpg)

Comment: It will be really helpful if you type the contents of your array in code, not ina an image, otherwise someone will need to type that for you.

Comment: Added example with your elements. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**. You can use any number of different loops approaches to do what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry, posted the wrong response before. Look at the use of a library to make this really easy [_countBy](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy)

```
var els = []; 

els.push({"ID":13,"PO_ID":1,"PO_NM":"Chemical","POINT_NAME":"TES HFJGH KH"});
els.push({"ID":13,"PO_ID":1,"PO_NM":"Chemical","POINT_NAME":"KRUTIKA PATEL"});
els.push({"ID":14,"PO_ID":2,"PO_NM":"Electrical","POINT_NAME":"SDA SHFKJ KJSJDHF KJSHDKJ JK"});
els.push({"ID":14,"PO_ID":2,"PO_NM":"Electrical","POINT_NAME":"KJHG S DJKFH JSKJSDKJFH KJ"});
els.push({"ID":15,"PO_ID":3,"PO_NM":"Water","POINT_NAME":"ERTERSHFKJ HNSJFH KJS"});



var cnts = _.countBy(els,'PO_NM');
alert(JSON.stringify(cnts));
console.log(cnts);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/370mL2v2/4/

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

Look at the documentation for `.filter`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var els = []; 

els.push({ID: '13', 'POINT_NAME': 'TEST', PO_ID: '1', 'PO_NM': 'Chemical'});
els.push({ID: '14', 'POINT_NAME': 'TEST', PO_ID: '2', 'PO_NM': 'Electrical'});
els.push({ID: '15', 'POINT_NAME': 'TEST', PO_ID: '3', 'PO_NM': 'Chemical'});
els.push({ID: '16', 'POINT_NAME': 'TEST', PO_ID: '4', 'PO_NM': 'Electrical'});

var els2 = els.filter(function(word){
  return word.PO_NM == 'Chemical';
})

console.log(els2);

$(els2).each(function(i){
    alert(els2[i].PO_NM + ' ' + els2[i].ID);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/370mL2v2/

Comment: Thanks for your response and i m very new in jquery and thank for give me knowledge about underscore js

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like an answer without underscore you can use this:

```js
var myArr = [
{ID: '1', 'prop1': 'val1', prop2: 'a', prop3: 'value1'},
{ID: '2', 'prop1': 'val1', prop2: 'b', prop3: 'value3'},
{ID: '3', 'prop1': 'val2', prop2: 'b', prop3: 'value1'}
];

function countObjects(arr, prop) {
 var results = {};
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var name = arr[i][prop];
  if(results.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
   results[name] = results[name] + 1;
  } else {
   results[name] = 1;
  }
 }
 return results; 
}

console.log(countObjects(myArr, "prop1"));
console.log(countObjects(myArr, "prop2"));
console.log(countObjects(myArr, "prop3"));
```